# Will portable air con cool as well as temperature increases?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have a portable air conditioner, it's currently reducing my room from 23-24C to 17-18C. 24C is not exactly hot and the main purpose of the unit is for when it does get hotter. I could expect my room to reach 30C. Will the AC be able to reach it's target of say 18C under 30C conditions? Will it take a longer time to reach it?

Comment: With the information provided it is impossible to answer.  It will certainly take longer to cool a room from 30C to 18C than to cool from 24C to 18C no matter what the capacity of the air conditioner is.  However we would need to know the capacity of the air conditioner (preferably make and model), size of the  room, type of insulation in the room walls, what direction the room faces, etc. to determine if it will do the job.

Comment: Hi Barry, It is a Suki 2.6kw, 10,000 BTU, Model EUR626HC. The room is roughly 20m sq and the unit is rated for 30m sq. I believe the walls should have batting in them. The room gets the most sun on it in the late afternoon, about 3-4PM.

Comment: Different questions. One relates to venting the other general cooling effectiveness. I was asked to separate my questions so did.